# How to port a Java game to an Android Application

Tags: java, android

I'm just curious, I am interested in making my game available in the Google play store. but I am not sure exactly how I would do this. I already have a google play developer account, but now what?

Would I basically use the same code I already have? or do I have to recode most of the game?

Comment: It has to be remade for android, and depending on how it was made there are tools for automating most of it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your game developed.

if it's based on the game engine like: libGDX,OGRE，etc. you can easily remove to android.

If it was not, i am afraid you may need develop it again based on ADK.